# how to get yesterday instance from jdatechooser

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

The user needs to select any date (Userdate). I need to set another jdate one day behind this date (needdate). Can you help with this?

```
Date date1 = (Userdate.getDate(),-1);
needdate.setDate(date1)
```

Comment: `LocalDate.now().plusDays(-1)` will give a `LocalDate` of yesturday

Comment: Thanks for replay, I need to go one day back from the selected date in jdate.

Comment: There's no such thing as `jdate` and the basic concept of using a `LocalDate` and adding/subtract date components to it is your starting point

Comment: Don't use a `java.util.Date`, use a `java.time.LocalDate` and simply subtract a day, e.g. `LocalDate aDayBefore = someSelectedLocalDate.minusDays(1);`.

Comment: exactly what i'm trying to do, get yesterday instance from jdatechooser

Comment: Which library is actually providing the `JDateChooser`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why everyone is telling you to use the new **java.time** package classes like **LocalDate** and **LocalDateTime** etc is because **Date** is quite old and known to be error prone. But hey...if you're bent on using ***Date*** then I suppose you can do it this way:

```
// Get the date from the JDateChooser
Date date = jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getDate();

// Subtract one day from the selected JDateChooser date.
Date oneDayFromSelectedDate = new Date(date.getTime() - Duration.ofDays(1).toMillis());

// Define the format you want the Date String;
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

// Dump it into a String variable and...
String myDateString = sf.format(oneDayFromSelectedDate);

//  Display it into the Console Window
System.out.println(myDateString);
```

The `oneDayFromSelectedDate` is the Date object containing the JDateChooser selected date *less one day*. Do consider changing to the java.time package.